# Не могу найти создателя сервера.Помогите

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Ошибка: NonType object has no attribute mention

Не пойму что не так

Код:

```
@bot.command()
async def si(ctx):
 emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Информация о сервере',color =0x9208ea)
 emb.add_field(name='Название Сервера', value=ctx.message.guild.name)
 emb.add_field(name='Owner', value=f"{ctx.guild.owner.mention}", inline=True)
 emb.add_field(name='Дата Создания', value=ctx.guild.created_at.strftime("%d %m %Y"), inline=True)
 emb.add_field(name='Участники', value=f'{ctx.guild.member_count} Участников', inline=True)
 emb.add_field(name='Каналы', value=f'Текстовых : {len(ctx.guild.text_channels)}  | Голосовых {len(ctx.guild.voice_channels)} ', inline=True)
 emb.add_field(name=' Сервера', value=f"{ctx.guild.id}", inline=True)
 emb.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url) 
 emb.set_footer(text="⭐")
 emb.set_author( name=f'{ctx.author.name}',icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url )

 await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: `Intents` включены?

Comment: Да,
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/940639950397898768/950416694592020490/unknown.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте включить Server Members Intent.
Так же, проверьте, указали ли вы intents в коде.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)
```

[image: Где находится Server Members Intent]